# Kubernetes v1.20 endpoints resource cannot view controller manger or scheduler

Tags: kubernetes

I want to check the election of basic components, but the information displayed is different in different versions of kubernetes binary installation methods.

Is the corresponding information cancelled in kubernetes v1.20 +? Or is there any other way to view the election of basic components?

The following kubernetes configuration parameters are consistent, except that the binary executable file is replaced

> Kubernetes v1.20.8 or Kubernetes v1.20.2

```
$ kubectl get endpoints -n kube-system
No resources found in kube-system namespace.
```

> Kubernetes v1.19.12

```
$ kubectl get endpoints -n kube-system
NAME                      ENDPOINTS   AGE
kube-controller-manager   <none>      9m12s
kube-scheduler            <none>      9m13s
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the cause of the problem

The difference between the two versions is the default value of `--leader-select resource-lock`

> Kubernetes v1.20.8 or Kubernetes v1.20.2

```
--leader-elect-resource-lock string        The type of resource object that is used for locking during leader election. Supported options are 'endpoints', 'configmaps', 'leases', 'endpointsleases' and 'configmapsleases'. (default "leases")
```

> Kubernetes v1.19.12

```
--leader-elect-resource-lock string        The type of resource object that is used for locking during leader election. Supported options are 'endpoints', 'configmaps', 'leases', 'endpointsleases' and 'configmapsleases'. (default "endpointsleases")
```

When I don't set `--leader-select-resource-lock` string in `controller-manager` or `scheduler` in v1.20.8, the default value is leaders.

so I can use the following command to view the information of component leaders.

```
$ kubectl get leases -n kube-system
NAME                      HOLDER                                                      AGE
kube-controller-manager   master01_dec12376-f89e-4721-92c5-a20267a483b8   45h
kube-scheduler            master02_c0c373aa-1642-474d-9dbd-ec41c4da089d   45h
```